# Convert utf8 without bom to utf 8

Tags: php

### Files

- index.php :

  ```
  <?php
  include_once 'index_a.php';
  ?>
  ```
- index_a.php :

  ```
  <html>
      <head>
          <title>test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          casa
      </body>
  </html>
  ```

### Results

The first result is from the `index.php` and the second `index_a.php`.

[image: first result is from the index.php and the second index_a.php]

Why I defend those quotes?

If `index_a.php` converts the file in UTF-8 without BOM, quotation marks do not appear, but I want the file to be encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: If you want to set your file to `UTF-8` Then put this line of code in your header: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` Also is this all your code whats in the `index.php` file is?

Comment: Depending on your IDE or editor, you should be able to save the file with a particular encoding. What are you using to write your code?

Comment: The best way to check which encoding your files have is Notpad++!

Comment: This is an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You want to solve the issue of empty strings showing up when there's no BOM, and assumed the problem is caused by the flavour of UTF8 encoding used in your file, then asked how to fix the file encoding. However, that's not the actual reason you're seeing those strings. You need to tell the browser which parsing rules it *must* use, by adding a doctype, which prevents it from guessing based on things like the file encoding.

Comment: @Chris if your unsing Notpad++ then it's the best and you can easy follow my answer how to change the encoding

Comment: I tried but it's all so md-tube.com/publicitate/index.php

Comment: @Chris if i look to the page source it don't see this quotes! What is your problem now?

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans problem is only in google chrome

Comment: @Chris It seems like that you show us the code from Chrome's inspect tool panel. **This is the rendered HTML output. If you need it as it is, please use "show source" (CTRL + U under most operating systems).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change your encoding of your Files i would sugguest you to use [Notpad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.6.9.html)!

After you installed it you can open your files in it and change the encoding like this:

(See point "Convert to UTF-8")

[image]

UPDATE:

This should work for you:

index.php:

```
<?php
    include_once 'index_a.php';
?>
```

index_a.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        casa
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried and I gave it convert UTF-8 but still no work.

Comment: @Chris what you mean with "still no work" what you want to work?

Comment: @Chris Then try to set a `DOCTYPE` with `<!DOCTYPE html>` and or set the encoding in the file itself with: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in the header section

Comment: I added your version but same problem

Comment: @Chris what problem? If i go to your test server i don't have this quotes int the page source?!?

Comment: the problem is from the notepad ++ ftp plugin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63895/discussion-between-chris-and-rizier123).

Answer (score 2):

you question doesn't make sense: UTF8 file encoding may (but shouldn't, as the byte ordering for UTF8 is fixed) have a BOM. In both cases your file will be UTF8 encoded, so you're done already. What happened here is that you've asked an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

So, what you *really* want to know is: why do those quotes show up for a normal UTF8 encoded file without BOM, but not when there is a BOM, and the answer to that is that you're giving the browser HTML code that could be any version of HTML, and expect it know which version you want rendered.

Without any knowledge of the document type, the browser may, or may not, treat any whitespace between tags as a single whitespace, or no whitespace, depending on the rendermode it guessed you wanted. So if you *really* don't want that `" "` then you shouldn't rely on the file encoding, you should make it explicit to the browser that what you're giving it to render is proper HTML. Add

```
<!doctype html>
```

at the top so that all browsers know this is a modern HTML5 content file and should be parsed accordingly, rather than falling back into an unpredictable quirks mode.

**edit**

http://jsbin.com/helikafuni/1/ shows proper HTML5 doctype and element use (you're using *ancient* HTML4.1 syntax. It's time to read up on how HTML5 changed a lot of the rules and use those new rules instead)

Comment: why does that have <!doctype> twice? Also, why are you using the HTML5 doctype and then immediately claim it's also XHTML? Don't do that, it's just `<!doctype html>` and then `<html>`. With a normal HTML5 meta tag: `meta charset="utf-8">`.

Comment: I've added a "proper" example for you to see what modern HTML5 looks like for your example.

Comment: where to put <! DOCTYPE html> in index.php or index_a.php

Comment: @Chris in the `index_a.php` file since there is your html

Comment: I added your version but same problem

Comment: Your content's loose in the `<body>` now, so it's a good idea to put that in an element with actual rules for how to parse text like a `<p>` or something and see what happens, and you need to remove that whitespace between head and body as well as change "DOCTYPE" to "doctype" (new rules matter)